# Hardhat Test Error "Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'deposit more' "

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, web3js, hardhat

Getting an error as `Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'deposit more'` on Hardhat Test.js file

**Test.js ->**

```js
    it("should abe to withdraw if no one apply", async function() {
    const salary = "10" + "000000000000000000";
    const jobDesc = "https://example.com";
    const startBalance = await addrs[0].getBalance();
    const duration = 30 * 86400;
    
    //await addrs[0].sendTransaction({ to: tasksV1.address, value: salary });
    
    //taskid should be 3
    await tasksV1.connect(addrs[0])
    .createTask(duration, jobDesc, { value: salary });
    const taskId = 3;
    
    await tasksV1.connect(addrs[0]).cancelTask(taskId);
    await tasksV1.connect(addrs[0]).withdrawDeposit(taskId);
    const newBalance = await addrs[0].getBalance();
    
    expect(startBalance.sub(newBalance).div("1000000000000000000")).equal(0);
    });
```

**Solidity Function ->**

```cpp
    function withdrawDeposit(uint256 taskId) external {
    require(tasks[taskId].creator == msg.sender, "Not creator");
    require(tasks[taskId].deposit > 0, "deposit more");
    require(
    tasks[taskId].status == TaskStatus.failed
    ||
    (tasks[taskId].status == TaskStatus.cancelled && applicants[taskId].length == 0)
    ||
    (tasks[taskId].status == TaskStatus.cancelled && block.timestamp > tasks[taskId].createdTime + unlockTime)
    , "Cannot withdraw");
    
    uint256 valueToWithdraw = tasks[taskId].deposit;
    tasks[taskId].deposit = 0;
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(valueToWithdraw);
    
    emit TaskUpdate(taskId, msg.sender, TaskActions.withdraw);
    }
```

I figured out that this error comes from Solidity function `require(tasks[taskId].deposit > 0, "deposit more");`

So, I even tried `const salary = ethers.utils.parseEther("10"); // 10 Ether in Wei` with this

But still getting the same error

Here's full code for better understanding -> https://github.com/akashpanda122/gig_board

***Been stuck in this for a very long time!***

Comment: I checked https://github.com/akashpanda122/gig_board/blob/web3/contracts/TasksV1.sol, but I dont see anywhere where you set the value for `tasks[taskId].deposit` (besides setting to `0`). Have you set it to a non-zero value somewhere in the smart contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing the GitHub link. The issue here is that in **createTask**() function, there are three arguments. But in your test, you are passing only two i.e **duration** and **jobDesc**. So I ran your test with the third argument which is **refId**. Now it is working fine. Please look at the attached screenshot.

[image: Test]

Comment: Thank you so much! :)

Getting another error! Please can you look at this also

"
 request and dispute
         should able request and resolve dispute:

      AssertionError: expected '0' to equal '500000000000000000'
      + expected - actual
"

Comment: The issue is the same, in your first test "create a task" while creating both tasks you have to pass the third argument. Then it will work fine